# How to pass id of product to parameter ajax for query on select2 server side codeigniter

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, jquery-select2

i wanted to ask. i had problem too catch id from detail product and pass it to controller and my first try shows [object Object] $abc123. how to make that from object Object to string like [object Object] $abc123 become $abc123 only?
i wanted too make my select2 just showin what uom avalaible for product abc123 only.

this is my source code
JS.

```
$("#selUom").select2({
        ajax: {
            url: '<?=base_url("transaksi/get/uom")?>',
            type: "post",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: function(params) {
                return {
                    idprod: params+'<?php echo $detprod["productcode"]; ?>',
                    searchTerm: params.term // search term
                };
            },
            processResults: function(response) {
                return {
                    results: response
                };
            },
            cache: true
        }
    });
```

Controller

```
public function allUom(){
    $searchTerm = $this->input->post('searchTerm');
    $idprod     = $this->input->post('idprod');
    $response   = $this->M_Mstuom->allBasedUom($idprod,$searchTerm);

    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

model

```
public function allBasedUom($id, $searchTerm=""){
    $this->db->select('m.uomid, m.uom');
    $this->db->join("msuom m", "m.uomid = pu.uomid");
    $this->db->where("m.uom like '%" . $searchTerm . "%' ");
    $this->db->where("pu.productcode", $id);
    $this->db->where("m.isactive", "t");
    $fetched_records = $this->db->get('msproductuom pu');
    $uom = $fetched_records->result_array();
    $data = array();
    foreach ($uom as $uom) {
        $data[] = array("id" => $uom['uomid'], "text" => $uom['uom']);
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try to use :
$("#selUom").select2({
        ajax: {
            url: '<?=base_url("transaksi/get/uom")?>',
            type: "post",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: function(params) {
                return {
                    idprod: params.'<?php echo $detprod["productcode"]; ?>',
                    searchTerm: params.term // search term
                };
            },
            processResults: function(response) {
                return {
                    results: response
                };
            },
            cache: true
        }
    });
```

Comment: still can't sir.. i need the id from <?php echo $detprod["productcode"]; ?> for selecting uom based product who's set before.